# The -v(--volume) seems to be lazy! A bizarre behavior

Tags: docker, dockerfile, fast-reverse-proxy

#### Problem description

The behavior of -v seems to be lazy, which leading to a `no such file or directory` [image: error]

The following is what I have done.

1. Build image from a go project named [frp](https://github.com/fatedier), here is my Dockerfile

   ```
   FROM golang:rc-alpine AS builder
   WORKDIR /builddir
   COPY . /builddir/
   RUN GO111MODULE=on CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -trimpath -ldflags "-s -w" -o bin/frps ./cmd/frps

   FROM scratch
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY --from=builder /builddir/bin/frps /app/
   ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/frps"]
   CMD [ "-c /etc/frp/frps.ini" ]
   ```

   Note that I use the config file at `/etc/frp/frps.ini` that does not exist in the image
2. I build image successfully, you can pull the image from the repository 290007431/frps:v0, but I ran into problem when I try to run it.
3. I pull the image from my ubuntu VPS, and create a config file on the /etc/frp/frps.ini

   ```
   [common]
   # A literal address or host name for IPv6 must be enclosed
   # in square brackets, as in "[::1]:80", "[ipv6-host]:http" or "[ipv6-host%zone]:80"
   bind_addr = 0.0.0.0
   bind_port = 9000

   dashboard_addr = 0.0.0.0
   dashboard_port = 7500
   ```
4. Then I use the next command to run

   ```
   docker run -d \
   -p 9000:9000 \
   -v /etc/frp:/etc/frp/:ro \
   --name frps \
   290007431/frps:v0
   ```

   The file not existing error comes here.

## What I have checked

1. docker logs to get the error information, shown as the first figure.
2. docker contain cp to copy the file inside the stopping container to check whether the /etc/frp/frps.ini exists, the answer is YES!!!!

## How I get over it

I use the command

```
docker run -d \
-p 9000:9000 \
-v /etc/frp:/etc/frp/:ro \
--name frps \
290007431/frps:v0 echo /etc/frp/frps.ini
```

You see, just add the  `echo /etc/frp/frps.ini` on the tail, the app can now find the config file in container. Here is the [image: result]

What's more, I find that any additional command on the tail will make it work!
**This confuse me a lot**

**I know that the `ENTRYPOINT` will override any cmd** but why the later `docker run` get into successful run? Is there a lazy volume load policy under the hood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMD` has two flavors. It can be written like a shell command without square brackets in which case Docker will perform word splitting, like so:

```
CMD -c /etc/frp/frps.ini
```

Or you can use the square bracket syntax to tell it exactly what the arguments are, like so:

```
CMD ["-c", "/etc/frp/frps.ini"]
```

What you wrote is a mix of the two:

> ```
> CMD [ "-c /etc/frp/frps.ini" ]
> ```

This looks like two arguments but it's actually a single argument with an embedded space in it.

I suspect frps then parses this like most UNIX utilities do where option arguments can be appended to the options, as in `-c<filename>`. It interprets `"-c /etc/frp/frps.ini"` as `"-c"` followed by the file name `" /etc/frp/frps.ini"`.

Notice that the file name has a leading space. That's why you're getting file not found. It's not opening the path you want it to. If you look closely you can see the extra space in the error messages:

```
Error: open  /etc/frp/frps.ini: no such file or directory
            ^
2021/01/29 17:10:27 [I] [root.go:108] frps uses config file:  /etc/frp/frps.ini
                                                             ^
```

> What's more, I find that any additional command on the tail will make it work!

When you provide your own command you're overwriting the `CMD` from the Dockerfile, getting rid of the problematic `-c`.